# How can i read arabic words from a pdf in python?

Tags: python, csv, pdf, arabic, text-extraction

In a project I'm currently working on, I need to extract Arabic text from a PDF. I have tried different libraries, and so far, the PyPDF2 library seems to be the best option for my needs.

However, I'm facing an issue with the output of the extracted text. The text appears to be incorrect, particularly when it contains Arabic words with Latin characters in the middle. I suspect this has something to do with the Right-to-Left (RTL) writing direction in Arabic.

Here is an example of the code I'm currently using:

```
import csv
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

# Open the PDF file
pdf_file = open('1.pdf', 'rb')

# Create a PDF reader object
pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)

# Get the first page
first_page = pdf_reader.pages[0]

# Extract text from the first page
arabic_text = first_page.extract_text()

# Close the PDF file
pdf_file.close()

# Write the extracted text to a CSV file
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(['Arabic Text'])  # Write the header
    writer.writerow([arabic_text])  # Write the text in a row

print("Extraction complete. The text has been saved to 'output.csv'.")
```

Here's an example of the PDF content:

> الكتاب: حماية الملكية الفكرية في الفقه الإسلامي والآثار الاقتصادية
> المترت بة

And here's the corresponding output from the script:

> الكتاب: محاية امللكية الفكرية يف الفقه اإلسالمي واآلاثر االقتصادية
> املرتت ِّبة

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to handle the RTL writing direction and ensure accurate extraction of Arabic text from the PDF. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you share the PDF itself, or maybe just that bit of text in an open Google Drive file or something?

Comment: Here is the file: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Isim2_vYoelf1KgJ28efD39I5bq_HXVy/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: First thing about PDFs is that it contains glyphs (laid out visually) rather than actual text. It uses the ToUnicode tables in the PDF (based on a fonts cmap tables) to convert glyphs to characters. Looking at your input string and output string a few things are happening. It is using a naive conversion of visual to logical layout for the text. the reversal appears to be occurring before ligatures in the font are converted to individual characters, ie ligatures are converted in visual rather than logical order within a string that has already been rendered logically.

Comment: The PDF is a tagged PDF, if the tags have ActualText attributes, it may be possible to walk the tag tree and extract the text from the ActualText attributes. Unfortunately this is probably the only way to handle any complex script text. It isn't just a question of resolving bidirectional issues, you also need to address ligatures and complex rendering reordering that is generating the glyph layer.